# Why is my new laptop's fan making noises?

Tags: laptop, fan, noise

I have a 1 month old Lenovo Ideapad y410p and the fan makes a weird clicking noise. It happens sometimes when I tilt my laptop but not always, sometimes when I turn on my laptop, and usually when I'm running CPU intensive programs. 
I tried opening the laptop and looking at the fan but I couldn't get the cover of the fan off because one of the screws wouldn't come out.

This is the sound it makes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIutZZoZb_8
(the noise that starts 4 seconds in is my AC not my computer)

It sometimes gets louder when I tilt the laptop. And when I'm playing video games it usually goes on the whole time.

Comment: Send it back! It's only 1 month old, let them fix instead of your trying to do something which could affect your warranty

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**

Send it back.

**Explanation**

This is probably a manufacturing fault. A lot of PC parts are injection molded and as such, they have a small chance of having excess material.

A good example of this would be on the bottom of plastic bottles, there is a small "pip".

The chances are, this is a small piece of plastic, which when the laptop is tilted just catches on the fan.

I cannot stress enough: *Do not attempt to fix it yourself, it could cause you to invalidate your warranty.*